# in python, what to write to get the value of (data-brand-name)

Tags: python

what to write to get the value of (data-brand-name)

```
data-brand-name which is"procos"
```

when I tried

brand = container.div['data-brand-name']

it is not working

also I tried

brand= container.find['data-brand-name']

and it is not working too

This is python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

page_url = "url.xml"

out_filename = "result.csv"
headers = "price,brand \n"

with open(out_filename, "w") as fw:
  fw.write(headers)
  with open("url.xml", "r") as fr:
    for url in map(lambda x: x.strip(), fr.readlines()): 
      print(url)
      uClient = uReq(url)
      page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

      containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class' : 'column column-block block-grid-large single-item'})

      for container in containers:

          price = container.find('span',{'class':'itemPrice'}).text 
          brand = container.div['data-brand-name']

          print(brand,price)
          fw.write(price + "," + brand)
```

and this is the part of the HTML code  and there multiple values for column column-block block-grid-large single-item

```
  <div class="column column-block block-grid-large single-item"
    data-brand-name="procos"
    data-category-name="party supplies"
    data-id-winner-unit="17971200500"
    data-ean="2724623306292"
    data-name="Procos Cinderella 11 Triangle Flag Banner, Unisex">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12">
      <div class="img-bucket">
          <div class="item-discounts">
```

Error

```
  File "C:\Users\A-Data\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\60perpage\a1.p
y", line 22, in <module>
    title = container.div['data-name']
  File "C:\Users\A-Data\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\bs4\element.py", line 1368, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'data-name'
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error? Or is it simply not printing? What is the exact problem?

Comment: question updated and error added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once you get your containers you are not indexing into them correctly in your for loop.

For example, this is what `containers` looks like:

```
<div class="column column-block block-grid-large single-item" data-brand-name="procos" data-category-name="party supplies" data-ean="2724623306292" data-id-winner-unit="17971200500" data-name="Procos Cinderella 11 Triangle Flag Banner, Unisex">\n<div class="row">\n<div class="columns small-12">\n<div class="img-bucket">\n<div class="item-discounts">\n</div></div></div></div></div>]
```

Notice that there is no `<span>` element. This is why your `price` variable was failing. Second, the attribute `data-brand-name` is already at the top-level. To make your for loop work, you can simply write:

```
price = container.find('div').text 
brand = container['data-brand-name']
print(price, brand)
```

In this example, the output is:

```
(u'\n\n\n\n', u'procos')
```

Comment: work great , you are smart hero, thank you very much